# Should we observe nawafil on the Night of 27th Rajab?

Tags: salat, time, lunar-calendar

Is there any ibadah prescribed by Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) for the night of 27th Rajab?

Comment: We should observe nawafil anytime and we shouldn't specify any day or time for that unless we have a proof. So why in your opinion should we chose the night of 27th Rajab?

Comment: In my area, special zikar was held and nawafil were prayed in mosques on shab e mairaj (27th Rajab). So. I just wanted to know that has Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) or any of his(peace be upon him) companions (may ALLAH be pleased with them) have said about any ibadah on this night or not. Because its better to follow Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) and his Companions (may ALLAH be pleased with them).

Comment: There's no authentic source for this date being the date of israa' and mi'raj however many Moslems think so. Imam as-Suyuti wrote a book quoting all dates for this night and the 27th of Rajab wasen't among those who might have stronger evidences for being this special night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a Sunni point of view, there is nothing special about Rajab 27<sup>th</sup> (or Sha'ban 15<sup>th</sup> for that matter). One should not observe these occasions with any special additional acts (prayers, fasting, etc.). Additional acts of worship are always good to perform, but one should not single out a specific time or place as being special without a form of endorsement from the Prophet (ﷺ).

Note that Rajab 27<sup>th</sup> is allegedly [*Laylat Al-Isra' wa Al-Mi'raj*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isra_and_Mi%27raj) (Arabic: ليلة الإسراء والمعراج). However, there is no evidence from the Qur'an or the hadith of the Prophet (ﷺ) that specifies the date of *Laylat Al-Isra' wa Al-Mi'raj*.

---

### From Zad Al-Ma'ad

In [Zad Al-Ma'ad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zad_al-Ma%27ad) (Arabic: [زاد المعاد في هدي خير العباد](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?ID=4&flag=1&bk_no=127&RecID=0&srchwords=%CA%CE%D5%ED%D5%20%E1%ED%E1%C9%20%C7%E1%C5%D3%D1%C7%C1&R1=1&R2=0&hIndex=)) Vol. 1, p. 57, [Ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qayyim_al-Jawziyya) quoted his teacher, [Ibn Taymiyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Taymiyyah), responding to a question about which night is better,  *Laylat al-Qadr* (Arabic: لیلة القدر‎‎) or *Laylat Al-Isra wa Al-Mi'raj* (Arabic: الإسراء والمعراج):

> الكلام في مثل هذا يحتاج إلى علم بحقائق الأمور، ومقادير النعم التي لا
>   تعرف إلا بوحي، ولا يجوز لأحد أن يتكلم فيها بلا علم، ولا يعرف عن أحد من
>   المسلمين أنه جعل لليلة الإسراء فضيلة على غيرها، لا سيما على ليلة
>   القدر، ولا كان الصحابة والتابعون لهم بإحسان يقصدون تخصيص ليلة الإسراء
>   بأمر من الأمور ولا يذكرونها، ولهذا لا يعرف أي ليلة كانت
>
> Declarations about such matters requires knowledge and awareness of
>   the extent of blessings, that are unknown without a revelation. No one
>   should declare [anything] about said matters without knowledge. It is
>   not known that any of the Muslims attributed additional virtue to
>   *Laylat Al-Isra'* over other nights, especially over *Laylat Al-Qadr*. Neither the companions, nor those who followed them with good conduct,
>   intentionally dedicated *Laylat Al-Isra'* with any additional matters;
>   they did not even mention or know which night it was.
>
> وإن كان الإسراء من أعظم فضائله صلى الله عليه وسلم  ومع هذا فلم يشرع
>   تخصيص ذلك الزمان ولا ذلك المكان بعبادة شرعية، بل غار حراء الذي ابتدئ
>   فيه بنزول الوحي وكان يتحراه قبل النبوة لم يقصده هو ولا أحد من أصحابه
>   بعد النبوة مدة مقامه بمكة، ولا خص اليوم الذي أنزل فيه الوحي بعبادة ولا
>   غيرها، ولا خص المكان الذي ابتدئ فيه بالوحي ولا الزمان بشيء
>
> With *Isra'* being one of the greatest virtues given to the Prophet
>   (ﷺ), he did not dedicate that time or place with additional worship.
>   The [cave of Hira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hira), where the first revelation descended on the
>   Prophet (ﷺ) was a place that he used to frequent prior to the
>   prophethood. Neither the Prophet (ﷺ), nor any of his companions,
>   visited the cave during their stay in Mecca. Neither the day the
>   revelation descended, nor the place where the revelation started were
>   singled out as special.
>
> ومن خص الأمكنة والأزمنة من عنده بعبادات لأجل هذا وأمثاله كان من جنس
>   أهل الكتاب الذين جعلوا زمان أحوال المسيح مواسم وعبادات، كيوم الميلاد،
>   ويوم التعميد، وغير ذلك من أحواله
>
> Whoever dedicates special places or times with acts of worship
>   following this or that [not following what the Prophet (ﷺ) did], he
>   and his likes resemble the people of the Scripture, who turned the
>   time of specific occasions related to Jesus Christ into seasons of
>   worship, such as his day of birth [Christmas], the day of baptism, and
>   other occasions of his.
>
> وقد رأى عمر بن الخطاب رضي الله عنه جماعة يتبادرون مكانا يصلون فيه،
>   فقال: ما هذا؟ قالوا: مكان صلى فيه رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فقال:
>   أتريدون أن تتخذوا آثار أنبيائكم مساجد؟ إنما هلك من كان قبلكم بهذا، فمن
>   أدركته فيه الصلاة فليصل، وإلا فليمض
>
> 'Umar ibn al-Khattab saw a group of men racing to a specific place to
>   pray. He asked: "What is this?" They said: "This is a place where the
>   Prophet (ﷺ) prayed." He said: "Do you want to take the footsteps of
>   your prophets as mosques? This is what made those who were before you
>   perish. When it is the time of prayers, pray wherever you are,
>   otherwise go."
>
> <sub>*— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care.*</sub>

---

### From Ihya' 'Ulum Al-Din

In Ihya' 'Ulum Al-Din, [Al-Ghazali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ghazali) quoted the following [hadith](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=641&pid=853495&hid=17) attributed to Abu Huraira (*mawqoof*), not the Prophet (ﷺ):

> عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه قال: من صام يوم سبعة وعشرين من رجب، كتب الله
>   له صيام ستين شهرا، وهو اليوم الذي هبط فيه جبريل عليه السلام على النبي
>   صلى الله عليه وسلم بالرسالة
>
> Narrated that Abu Huraira said: Whoever fasts on the day of the
>   twenty-seventh of Rajab, Allah will award him the fasting of sixty
>   month; it is the day that Jibril (ﷺ) descended on the Prophet (ﷺ) with
>   the Message.
>
> <sub>*— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care.*</sub>

The chain of narration of this hadith is:

1. Abu Huraira
2. Shahr ibn Hawshab
3. Matar ibn Tahman
4. 'Abdullah ibn Shawthab
5. Damra ibn Rabee'a
6. 'Ali ibn Sa'id ibn Qutaiba Al-Ramli
7. Habshoon ibn Moosa ibn Ayuub
8. Ahmad ibn Ibrahim ibn Shathan

Shahr ibn Hawshab (Arabic: شهر بن حوشب) had integrity but forgot a lot, mixed things a lot, and often quoted with incorrect or without attribution. Matar ibn Tahman (Arabic: مطر بن طهمان) had integrity but committed lots of mistakes in narrations. This hadith is accordingly not authentic.

Comment: This means that  no extra ibadah is prescribed by Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) for 15th of Shaban also ?

Comment: @Student28 - This is correct. You may perform extra ibadah on any day, as extra ibadah is always something that Muslims should seek, but nothing is special about these days that we know from the sunnah of the Prophet (ﷺ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we should. I am not sure what the Sunni schools of thought recommend to do on this special night which leads to the proclamation of prophet hood of the final messenger Muhammad and several years later his ascension to the heavens on the 27th of Rajab.

The Shia school of thought recommends for example to perform **Ghusl** and a **12** **rakat prayer** to be performed in 2 rakat sequences (6x2 rakat). After Salaam recite the following Verses of the Holy Quran **7** **times each**.

Sura **Fatiha**,
Sura **Ichlas**,
Sura **Falaq**,
Sura **Naas**,
Sura **Kafiroon**,
Sura **Qadr**,
Ayat-ul-**Kursee**.

This [ibadah](http://www.duas.org/miraj.htm) is based on the Holy Imams of Ahl-ul-Bayt.